# What are best practices to maintain a list in the database in Rails?

Tags: database-design, ruby-on-rails, maintenance, relationships

I have list boxes and model relationships in the database. I'm doing the following migrations to maintain lists, rename items, and add items:

```
  def up
    Fund.create min: 0, max: 1_000_000
    add_column :sectors, :order, :integer, default: 0
    Sector.create name: 'Agriculture', order: 1
    Sector.create name: 'Construction', order: 2
    Sector.find( 9).update! name: 'Consumer Products', order: 3
```

This will work until I must rollback a migration, then the primary keys for new rows in development will no longer match the ones in staging or production. I thought about installing ActiveAdmin, but then I would have to manually change 3 different databases (dev/staging/prod). Both ways seem tedious. I thought about `#delete_all` but there are foreign key constraints, and there are already users using the lists in production. Is there a Rails convention to update and add to lists in the database?

---

Oh yeah, I've also tried created lists in the code to more easily maintain them, like

```
class Ownership
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :id, :name

  def self.all
    [
      { id: 1, name: 'Individual' },
      ...
   ].map { |v| Ownership.new v }
  end

  def self.find_by_id(id)
    Ownership.all.select do |v|
      v.id == id
    end
  end
```

But then whenever I have to print one of the values, I have to look it up by `id` first. So instead of `@record.ownership.name` I have to use `@ownership = Ownership.find_by_id(@record.ownership_id); @ownership.name;`.

---

Oh yeah, I've also done this, when really pressed for time, which is the worst:

```
User Model:
  @@list_options = %w[0 1-5 6-10 10+]
  def self.list_options
    @@list_options
  end

User View:
  =f.select :field_1yr, User.list_options.map.with_index{|x,i| [x,i]}
```

Comment: From my point of view, if you create entities in migration rolling it back should delete them regardless of foreign key constraints (make sure that related entities are also deleted/adjusted). However, I don't know how this all is related to the concept of a list, can you clarify?

Comment: Yes the ones I just created are easily deleted, but the old ones that are used gives errors like 'foreign key constraint id 1 is in use by users table' (or similar).

Comment: Why do your primary keys in production need to match those in development? It's not like you're going to have a foreign key from a production table referenced by a row in a development table. Also, you should be able to write a custom 'down' migration that undoes exactly what your 'up' migration does, to enable rolling back properly.

Comment: @SeanBurton They don't _have_ to, but it's really nice and helpful (and OCD compliant) when they do. That way you can write queries without `order by`, hardcode the primary key in the code for comparisons, and it's easier to maintain and update referencing the `id` only.

Comment: If you're hardcoding primary keys in your code then you are doing things terribly wrong. It sounds like what you want is a separate indexed enum column...

Comment: @SeanBurton Yes, that is what I shall do! I shall make a short text column with string keys like 'real_estate1', 'real_estate2', etc.

Comment: An enum column should really be an integer as comparing integers is faster than comparing strings. The names of each value are then defined in the code.

Comment: It sounds like you are assuming that primary keys are allocated sequentially in increasing order. This will not be true if you run an Oracle database on clustered servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do the following. It's just as tedious, but at least it doesn't depend on the primary key.

```
Sector.create name: 'Real Estate - Commercial', order: 20 
Sector.find_by_name('Real Estate (Residential/Commercial)').update! name: 'Real Estate - Residential', order: 21
...
```

---

I like this way best, to use a short, fixed, unique code to reference the row, and have an `order` column so sort by. Although ideally `order` will be by increments of 10's, to allow insertions without renumbering everything.

```
 id |      code      | order |                             name                             |         created_at         |         updated_at
----+----------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  1 | finance        |     1 | Financial Services                                           | 2017-12-17 04:11:02.818388 | 2017-12-17 04:11:02.818388
  2 | energy         |     2 | Energy                                                       | 2017-12-17 04:11:02.823391 | 2017-12-17 04:11:02.823391
  3 | waste          |     3 | Waste to Energy Technologies                                 | 2017-12-17 04:11:02.828391 | 2017-12-17 04:11:02.828391
```